# Difference between .NET Assembly Manifest and Visual Studio csproj files

Tags: c#, .net, manifest, csproj

Does a C# manifest file allow you to declare dependencies? It looks like manifests have to do with configuring and building .NET Assemblies, while csproj files enable building Visual Studio projects (via MSBuild) and also enable declaring dependencies among other information.

I would be interested to know if all dependency management in a Visual Studio project can be pushed to the manifest and if there is any advantage to this; ex. msbuild vs csc, decoupling from IDE or platform, etc.

See MS Documentation (Assembly Reference List):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/index

Comment: They are already used that way, that's how a library DLL ends up in the build directory of an EXE project.  "All dependency management" is not a realistic goal, somebody has to generate that manifest and that egg needs to come before the chicken.  The compiler cannot do this until the project file says what reference assemblies it needs to use.

Comment: Or in another way, the manifest does not exist until you compile the assembly out, so the project file is always the master source, and the manifest file has no advantage as far as I can see.